# Number of FULL binary trees

Tags: binary-tree, computer-science, combinatorics

Consider binary trees where each node is either a leaf or possesses exactly two child nodes (left and right, which we consider different). 
How many different trees are there on `n` nodes?
For example:
 - 3 nodes -> 1 tree,
 - 4-> 0 tree,
 - 5 -> 2 trees,
 - 6 -> 0 tree,
 - 7 -> 5 trees,
 - and so on ...
 There is any formular for this sequence? I have found formular for all possible binary tree ([Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)) but I'm searching for **full** tree.

Comment: What's your ***programming*** question? Please be specific and include a [mcve] with your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a "full" tree, there are an odd number of nodes and every second node in order is a leaf.

If you remove all these leaves, you are left with a binary tree that might not be full.  For any (maybe not full) binary tree, there is exactly one way to add a leaf at the start, the end, and between each pair of nodes, to make a full binary tree.

So there is a 1-1 correspondence between binary trees with **n** nodes, and **full** trees with **2n+1** codes.

**C(n)** -- the catalan number -- is the number of binary trees with **n** nodes, and also therefore the number of "full" trees with **2n+1** nodes.

The number of full binary trees with **n** nodes is therefore **C((n-1)/2)**.  Since you can't have half a node, the answer is **0** when **n** is even.